# MATLAB: In this function, why won't it let me set the precision after the decimal point for reading data from a text file?

Tags: matlab, text, precision

I have written this function to read data from a text file and store it in a matrix, where the columns are variables and rows samples. Format spec can be used to define the precision.

```
  function A = readGivenData(dataFileName,noOfVariables,formatSpec)
  fileID = fopen(dataFileName,'r');
  [A,~] = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec,[noOfVariables inf]); 
  fclose(fileID);
  A = A';
  end
```

One of the variables has five places after the decimal point (the default with this function seems to be only 4) but using this function and inputting '%.5f' as the formatSpec simply returns a 0x0 empty char array. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: All of the decimals are read, MATLAB just outputs values rounded to 4 decimal places. Use `format long` to set up MATLAB to display 8 decimal places instead.

Comment: Does `'%f'` for `formatSpec` read the values correctly?

Comment: @User81862311 Yes it does, but it rounds them to 4 d.p.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks that works. Still confused why I can't use the fscanf method with '%.5f' though to get 5 d.p only.

Comment: `format long` only **displays** the value of a variable with 15 decimal places. It does not change the value of it. There is a difference between the display format and the actual value's precision.

Comment: Don’t know why it can’t be done, `scanf` just doesn’t work that way. The MATLAB function is modeled after the original C function, which also doesn’t take length specified like that. The format specifier of `scanf` is not the same as that of `printf`, though they have similarities.